# AngleSharp to get all HTML tags and assign a unique id attribute

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Is there any way I can use [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) to get all body tags count, and then assign a unique attribute id such as "data-id=1", "data-id=2" etc to all the tags.

I am looking to test this for a static website translation purpose, Then I will use the query selector [data-id] and take the TextContent from each tag and Translate the text using the translation API and Set back the translated text to tag id where it was extracted from originally.

**C#**

```
var html = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\example.html");
    var parser = new HtmlParser();
    var document = parser.Parse(html);

    var elements = document.All.Where(o => o.NodeType == AngleSharp.Dom.NodeType.Text && o.TextContent.Trim() != ""); // If text, assign id.
    if(elements != null)
    {
        int number = 0;
        foreach(var element in elements)
        {
            element.SetAttribute("data-id", number.ToString());
            number++;

            element.OuterHtml.Dump();
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My page heading</h1>
<h2>This is example static page to get all the HTML tags and their <strong>childrens content </strong> and then <span>translate</span>
that into </br> another language.
</h2>
<p>Something in footer</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the following does it. Basically it collects all descending elements from the Body element, loop over them and add the attribute. Perhaps you had trouble in looping over ALL the descendants.

I write the body's updated inner html to a text file just so you see the 'data-id' attributes are there.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var response = getHtml("http://www.bbc.com");
        var html = response.Result;

        HtmlParser htmlParser = new HtmlParser();
        var parsedDoc = htmlParser.Parse(html);
        var body = parsedDoc.Body;
        var elements = getAllElements(parsedDoc.Body);

        for(var i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
        {
            var child = elements[i];
            child.SetAttribute("data-id", $"data-id{i + 1}");
        }

        File.WriteAllText("E:/soQuestion.txt", parsedDoc.Body.InnerHtml);
    }

    static async Task<string> getHtml(string url)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            //if http request did not succeeed, return empty html
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return string.Empty;

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content;
        }

    }

    static List<IElement> getAllElements(IElement element)
    {
        List<IElement> elements = new List<IElement>();

        //add element itself
        elements.Add(element);

        foreach (var child in element.Children)
        {
            //add each child elements
            elements.AddRange(getAllElements(child));
        }

        return elements;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Any way to process the attribute text and set it back to original tag where it belongs to. I am looking to translate a static site using this.

Comment: Why not create a new Html, and add all the changes there, instead of trying to manipulate the original page source ? At the end simply use the newly generated html.

Comment: There might be risk of removing <script>, css, styles, comments etc in body if AngleSharp didn't  captured that in getAllElements what I am going to insert in my new HTML? Or it won;t ignore anything? Any example to build the HTML using my example HTML in question?